# Android App: How to prevent a user from re-installing an app that was previously installed and afterwards uninstalled?

Tags: android

Fundamentally, I want to keep track of user's device say some unique device-id which is then stored on a server when the user installs my app!and if it again tries to install my app after uninstalling, then the app should not be installed.
How may I achieve this?

Comment: If app cannot be uninstalled, how may I disable the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I think **you can't prevent user to re installing it**, But in your application you put a functionality which check database for device ID previously installed app if you found then you disable the functionality of your app.

Comment: I think He can do,but he needs to build some kind of patch.first it will install before the app on device and checks the re-installation  check of app from db.

Comment: @Last Warrior - In that case He has to install patch on every device which installed his app, its like the same thing without installing other app.

Comment: @LastWarrior Do you know its too easy for rooted phones to wipe the db

Comment: Ok that would be good if the functionality of the app is disabled on re-installation. but can you elaborate on which database and which device-id do I need to check?

Comment: m not asking to build DB at device.@ingsaurabh

Comment: First of all when your application installed and first time runs You have to get device ID and check your server database, If its not available then store it in and enable your app functionality, if its already available in database then disable app functionality. store the device _ID in your server database,

Comment: what exactly is the device_id that can be stored?

Answer (score 0):

You can't uninstall an application yourself (otherwise you would see viruses wiping our phones from the beginning) but you still can disable the application if the device is found in the database.

- create a connection to your server
- ask if the device is authorized
- close the app if you're not authorized

Answer (score 0):

//use this following code to find the app is installed or not
//your app package name is the unique id

//appUniqueIdStr -package name of the app

```
boolean installed  = appInstalledOrNot(appUniqueIdStr);
if(installed){
//dont install
}
else{
//install 
}


     /**
     * check app installed or not
     * @param uri is the package name of the app
     * @return boolean whether installed or not
     */
    private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri)
    {
        boolean app_installed = false;

        ListofAppinMyDevice getmyApp=new ListofAppinMyDevice();
        ArrayList<PInfo> apps  =getmyApp.getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */ 
        Log.e("hi", "apps==="+apps.toString());
        String uri_app=null;
        if(uri!=null)
        {
            uri_app=uri;
        }
        else 
        {
            uri_app=null;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++)
        {

            Log.e("pack name", "apps.get(i).pname.==="+apps.get(i).pname.toString());

            if(apps.get(i).pname.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(uri_app))
            {
                app_installed=true;
                Log.v("hi","im inside the loop");
                break;
            }   
        }

        Log.e("boo", "app_installed==="+app_installed);
        return app_installed ;
    }
```