# determine whether new installation or update

Tags: android

This is a tough one:
Lets say there is a SDK that was included in an app at some point. This app is available in the market for quite some time now, the SDK however is integrated since the newest version. So there are two ways for a customer to get to the app with SDK included:

1. The person did not have the app before and downloads the newest version
2. The person already had the app installed in an older version without the SDK and updates to the new version with SDK

Now when the app is opened for the first time, how can the SDK decide if the app was installed or updated?

Some things I thought of, without success:

- One could search for a file that was created when the app was installed and never altered from that point. Just look up the last-modified field and you know when the app was installed. I found the lib-file in data/data/ but it gets updated everytime the app gets updated, so there is no use. EDIT: The reason why it's import that the file has never been altered is that there is no way to access the file creation time, so we must be sure that last-modified == creation time
- The sdk should be compatible with Android 1.6, so it's < API 9 and I can't access the  PackageInfo.firstInstallTime field.
- I don't think I have access to data/app in order to look at the apk iteself, but even when i could, the apk gets replaced everytime I update the app, so last-modified would give me the time of last update, not installation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: prevent a user from re-installing an app that was previously installed http://stackoverflow.com/q/8426963/1012284

Comment: Sorry but I don't see a connection to my question.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things come to mind:

Store a version number in shared preferences. call it first install and if there is no value set set the current version number (this would happen only on first install, maybe in the Application class). Later you can check for the preference and compare it to the current version. when updating you will still have the first version code and compare it to the current one since you need to increment the version code when posting app updates.

Create a file on SDCard (best to be in mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.my.package.name/) if it doesn't exist. name it with the version code or something. You will then have the version code and the time created in case you need it. The good thing about that folder is that it persists when updating your app but gets deleted when uninstalling it ( con: i think that feature is available from API Level 8 and above you will have to check)

Same thing with the file but in the data/data/com.package.name folder on the phone memory (The databases are kept there also and your app is the only one that can access it - unless rooted) which will definitely get deleted when uninstalling and kept when updating.

Use a database helper to store the version codes and timestamps inside. the DB helper has a way of tracking the version of the database.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive answer. However, it only works when the SDK already was included in a previous version of the app. Example: User installs app without SDK. App gets an update with SDK. User updates his app. No previous version in shared prefs / sdcard / databases can be found, so it must be a new install. In reality it was an update so I get a wrong information.